# Ejected from Expo Error - SDK location not found

Tags: react-native, expo

I am making my first react native app and I have had to eject from Expo to add in app purchases.

I have gotten the error below and not quite sure what to do when running:

react-native run-android

I have tried adding "C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" as PATH environmental variable but has not solved the issue

Any ideas on what to try next?

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Swig\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 89

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Swig\android\local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 24s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Answer (score 0):

I had added the address to the PATH variables rather then its own

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup